# Indentation guide for the eclipse editor

Tags: eclipse, editor

Is there a setting or plugin for eclipse that can show indentation guides in the editor? Something like the [Codekana](http://www.codekana.com/) plugin for visual studio (not so fancy is also OK). Important that it works with PyDev.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EditBox since v0.0.20 is fixed for support Pydev. Thanks for reporting this. Some default preferences for Python included now, but you are welcomed to share yours [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/editbox/forums/forum/1036090).

Comment: Just downloaded release 0.0.20, it 's working great so far. There should be an update site as well so we don't miss new features. Great plugin.

Comment: Thank you for the great plugin and the amazing response time for the feature request!

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved this is [EditBox](http://editbox.sourceforge.net/). 
With some customization through it's preferences you can get to some nice code blocks  highlighting of python code (or any other where blocks are signified with whitespace).
It is highly customizable and can achieve the vertical rules codekana style, and various other layouts.

<strike>The problem is it doesn't work on PyDev editor from what I see (at least for now). I've opened a [feature request](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=285066&atid=1208334) for it.
If it's any good, you can still view it's layout when opening a python file with right click "Open With/Text editor".</strike> From version 0.20, EditBox fully supports PyDev.

I also tried [AnyEdit](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/anyedit/) which has some whitespace highlighting amongst other features, but was not too happy with the results. For example, I had to press they're "show whitespace" button after each change to show the background, and it's not very visually pleasing (it uses eclipse's annotations to highlight whitespace).

Comment: Thanks EditBox is what I 'm looking for. Hope it gets compatibility with PyDev.

Comment: Great stuff, I'm in love! If only it had different stroke styles. 1px dotted would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

The closest approximation would be to combine:

- showing the whitespace characters (which shows tabs and spaces, but not just tabs)
- code folding (available [with PyDev](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_features.html))

Comment: The first choice unfortunately adds too much noise while the second one is actually the method I currently use.

Answer (score 0):

[IndentGuide](https://github.com/sschaef/IndentGuide) is a plugin that does this for Eclipse. I am not sure whether it works for PyDev though.